# RewriteRule to execute multiple rules

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I need to proxy a request to a remote server that does not support CORS and simultaneously log the request to a database on my end.  While syntactically correct, this does not do what I want:

```
RewriteRule ^log/([0-9]+)$ log_hit_to_database.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^log/([9-9]+)$ http://www.example.com/log/$1 [P,L]
```

Right now I can't quite tell what it's doing; I see no indication that the remote service was called nor was my local script called.

I can tell this doesn't work because the first rule doesn't have the `L` flag, so Apache continues processing rules that can match.  Since the second one does, and it has the `L` flag, it settles on the second rule and discards the first.

In case it matters, the data needs to be `POST`ed to the remote server.

Is there any way to get Apache to "tee" the request?